# How can I get repository instance?

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, laravel-5, repository

I am quite new in Laravel repository.

I am using [l5-repository package](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository).

When I created resource controller, it created as following:

```
    public function __construct(MyRepository $repository, MyValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }
```

I could get `MyRepository` instance with `$this->repository` in this controller.

But I need to use another repository in this controller.

I tried to get like this but failed.

```
$anotherRepo = new AnotherRepo(); // I think AnotherRepo` is interface.
```

I was going to get `$anotherRepo->all()` data but couldn't get `$anotherRepo` instance.

Please help me how can I get repository instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass it into constructor and then access it like others.

```php
public function __construct(AnotherRepo $another, MyRepository $repository, MyValidator $validator)
{
    $this->another = $another;
    $this->repository = $repository;
    $this->validator  = $validator;
}
```

And then get it `$this->another`.